# Pyspark: How to build sum of a column(which contains negative and positive values) with stop at 0

Tags: pyspark, sum

I think a example says more then the describtion.
The right column "sum" is the one i am looking for.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9Qp0.png)

```
to_count|sum
-------------     
-1      |0
+1      |1
-1      |0
-1      |0
+1      |1
+1      |2
-1      |1
+1      |2
.       |.
.       |.
```

I tried to rebuild that with several groupings with comparing lead and lag but that only works for the first time the sum usually ends in a negativ value.

Summing only positive and negative values seperatly also ends in another final result.

Would be great if anyone has a good idea how to solve this in pyspark!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Dataset and calc]

Please look at the pic first there is a testdataset(first 3 columns) and the calc steps.

The column "flag" is now in another format. We also checked our datasource and realized that we only have to handle 1 and -1 entries. We mapped 1 to 0 and -1 to 1. Now it's working like exspected as you see in the column result.

The code is this:

```
w1 = Window.partitionBy('group').orderBy('order')
df_0 = tst.withColumn('edge_det',F.when(((F.col('flag')==0)&((F.lag('flag',default=1).over(w1))==1)),1).otherwise(0))
df_0 = df_0.withColumn('edge_cyl',F.sum('edge_det').over(w1))
df1 = df_0.withColumn('condition', F.when(F.col('edge_cyl')==0,0).otherwise(F.when(F.col('flag')==1,-1).otherwise(1)))
df1 =df1.withColumn('cond_sum',F.sum('condition').over(w1))
cond = (F.col('cond_sum')>=0)|(F.col('condition')==1)
df2 = df1.withColumn('new_cond',F.when(cond,F.col('condition')).otherwise(0))
df3 = df2.withColumn("result",F.sum('new_cond').over(w1))
```

Comment: oh, didn't know you only have `1` and `-1` here.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `pandas_udf` here:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType

pdf = pd.DataFrame({'g':[1]*8, 'id':range(8), 'value': [-1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1]})
df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
df = df.withColumn('cumsum', F.lit(math.inf))

@pandas_udf(df.schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def _calc_cumsum(pdf):
    pdf.sort_values(by=['id'], inplace=True, ascending=True)
    cumsums = []
    prev = 0
    for v in pdf['value'].values:
        prev = max(prev + v, 0)
        cumsums.append(prev)
            
    pdf['cumsum'] = cumsums
    return pdf

df = df.groupby('g').apply(_calc_cumsum)
df.show()
```

The results:

```
+---+---+-----+------+
|  g| id|value|cumsum|
+---+---+-----+------+
|  1|  0|   -1|   0.0|
|  1|  1|    1|   1.0|
|  1|  2|   -1|   0.0|
|  1|  3|   -1|   0.0|
|  1|  4|    1|   1.0|
|  1|  5|    1|   2.0|
|  1|  6|   -1|   1.0|
|  1|  7|    1|   2.0|
+---+---+-----+------+
```

Comment: That works but we also found a solution without pandas and without a loop. That is working faster for big datasets. I will post it imediatly. But thank you niuer for your fast solution!